# command prompt in c++

Tags: c++, command-prompt

Guys what am I doing wrong here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    while (true){
        std::string cmd;
        cin >> cmd;

        const char* com = cmd.c_str();

        cout << com << endl;
       // cout << sizeof(com) << endl;

        system(com);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Everytime I run this it works fine but when you type something like cd ../ it separates the words and runs them as two different commands so first cd, then ../ and it gives me a error. Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?
I'm new to C++ anyway also this is supposed to bypass "command prompt has been disabled by your admin on windows"

Comment: So `cout` will read until the first white space so `cd` and `../` are going to be read separately as white space separates the two.

Comment: and issuing a `cd` statement in a `system` call won't change current directory for next system calls...

Comment: problem is in `std::cin >>` which cant get white spaces use `std::cin.getline` instead

Comment: Use `std::getline(cin,cmd);` instead. Also note that `cd` won't have any effect regarding the working directory of your program.

Comment: And the root of the problem here is, of course, is that a computer only does what you tell it to do, and not what you want it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the extraction operator (>>) stops reading when reaching the first white-space if your command consists of spaces then use std::getline:

```
std::string sCommand;
std::cout << "Enter eommand: ";
std::getline(std::cin, sCommand); // eg enter: color 1f
system(sCommand.c_str()); // c_str(): converts from class string to const char*.
```

there's no way to pass two arguments one after the other to system when the first arguments invokes a program and the second is passed to it but you can make on big command then pass it.

```
system("diskpart"); // invoking diskpart
system("list vol"); // here list vol is not passed to diskpart but only to cmd  

system("notepad.exe C:/desktop/mylog.txt"); // ok
```

Comment: Based on the questioner's attempt to execute a "cd ../" it's likely he's not running Windows, but rather some variant of Unix.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner where did he get system?

Comment: @Raindrop7: `system()` is a standard C runtime function.

Comment: @Raindrop7: on 'nix systems, you can use `chdir("path")` instead of `system("cd path")`.

Comment: @Raindrop7: there is nothing in the OP's question that suggests Windows is being used.  But even then, some Windows compilers have `chdir()` available in their C runtimes. Either way, consider using something more portable instead, like [`boost::filesystem::current_path`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#current_path).

Comment: @RemyLebeau ok that is it

Comment: @RemyLebeau the identifier cmd doesn't mean windows?

Comment: @Raindrop7 Windows' command-line processor is `cmd.exe` in modern systems (it used to be `command.com` in old systems). But in the OP's example. `cmd` is just a `std::string` variable, and "cmd" is an abbreviation for "command", which happens to be the name of `system()`'s input parameter. `system()` invokes the host platform's command-line processor, whatever it happens to be. So still no explicit reference to Windows in the OP's code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127136/discussion-between-raindrop7-and-remy-lebeau).

Comment: Wow, I didn't actually think so many people r gonna answer this question, and yes I'm running Windows not linux or *nix

Comment: @HinaCh4n did it work for you? please edit the question specifying that you are on windows

Comment: >>Raindrop7 I will try it tommorow as it's 1am here and I do not have access to my computer right now

Comment: @HinaCh4n:   ok. then you are interested in `SetCurrentDirectory() API` to change current directory then pass to system the command

Comment: @Raindrop7 so to change directory I can filter the input and in case it matches cd I can use the SetCurrentDirectory api call but what library does it use Windows.h . Sorry I'm just really new to c++ or coding in general.

Comment: @HinaCh4n per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365530.aspx): "***Header** WinBase.h (include Windows.h) **Library**
Kernel32.lib
**DLL**
Kernel32.dll*"

Comment: @HinaCh4n: yes in windows.h